# Stop sticky Box on Wrapper bottom border

Tags: jquery

I have a sticky box on my page which have to stops on bottom border of wrapper but I don't know how to do it.
I think its very basic and simple but I just don't know how to.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('.sticky_div').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){ /*header-menu-wrap*/
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
        $('.woocommerce-tabs').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
        $('.woocommerce-tabs').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });  });
```

```css
.sticky_div {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
} 

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.woocommerce-tabs {
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 150px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    float: left;
    padding: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {height:700px; border-bottom:1px solid #000;}

.footer {height:700px; background:#ffe000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br>
  <div class="sticky_div">
   <div class="woocommerce-tabs">
   Content
   </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for sticky footer.

```
.footer{
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}

<div class="footer">Stays at the page bottom</div>
```

**Updated Answer #1**

```
<style type="text/css">
        .sticky_div {
            width: 250px;
            height: 150px;
        } 

        .sticky {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 250px;
            height: 150px;
            }

        .woocommerce-tabs {
            max-width: 250px;
            min-height: 150px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            padding: 25px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .container {
            height:700px; 
            border-bottom:1px solid #000;
        }

        .footer {
            height:700px; 
            background:#ffe000;
        }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('.sticky_div').offset().top;
        var footer_offset = $(".footer").offset().top;
        var woocommerce_tabs = $(".woocommerce-tabs").offset().top;
        var woocommerce_element_height = 150; // this height is set in css property
        var woocommerce_calc_height = woocommerce_tabs + woocommerce_element_height;

        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            $('.woocommerce-tabs').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('.woocommerce-tabs').removeClass("sticky");
        }

        if(woocommerce_calc_height >= footer_offset){
            $(window).scrollTop(footer_offset-woocommerce_element_height);
        }

    });  
});

</script>
```

**Updated Answer #2**
i'm posting the code here because it will be easy to read. This works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .sticky_div {

        } 

        .sticky {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            }

        .woocommerce-tabs {
            width: 250px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            padding: 25px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            float: left;
        }

        .container {
            height:700px; 
            border-bottom:1px solid #000;
        }

        .footer {
            height:700px; 
            background:#ffe000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br> <br><br><br>
  <div class="sticky_div"></div>
   <div class="woocommerce-tabs">
   Content
   </div>


</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 

        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('.sticky_div').offset().top;
        var footer_offset = $(".footer").offset().top;
        var woocommerce_tabs = $(".woocommerce-tabs").offset().top;
        var woocommerce_element_height = 150;


        if(window_top +woocommerce_element_height > footer_offset ){
            $('.woocommerce-tabs').css({'top' : ((window_top +woocommerce_element_height -footer_offset) * -1)});
        }
        else if(window_top  > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            $('.woocommerce-tabs').addClass("sticky");
            $('.woocommerce-tabs').css({'top' : 0});
        } else {
            $('.woocommerce-tabs').removeClass("sticky");
        }


    });  
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont need a sticky footer. the .sticky_div has to be sticky and has to stop on the bottom border of the container

Comment: i will try to do that, can you post your entire code in codepen or jsfiddle ..etc?

Comment: @Mel.Ak.i have updated the answer . check whether it works as per your question.

Comment: its almost perfect but the hole side stops to scroll wenn the sticky box hits the border. maybe my english is to bad to explain what i really want. The box stops on perfect position now the page just have to scroll like http://jsfiddle.net/0mLzseby/473/ this is perfect but i dont know how to figure it out

Comment: @Mel.Ak. you want both the sticky box and footer to scroll together when stickybox touches the footer? the latest fiddle you posted looks fine. what is the problem you want to fix in that?

Comment: @Mel.Ak. i think i understod what you are saying. let me try it

Comment: yeah that fiddle looks fine but i dont know what i have to do that my box do the same like in that last fiddl

Comment: @Mel.Ak. where you able to find the answer you wanted?

Comment: @Mel.Ak. i have updated my answer . check Updated Answer #2 . i think that is the output you were looking for. Let me know if the output is the one you expected,

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!